# Edit Pull Request comment for other users

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

We recently moved our Azure DevOps Server instance to another server, changing its public URL.
Because of this, any links/images in Pull Request comments are still pointing to the old URL.

I have written C# code to use the API to change the comments (UpdateCommentAsync), but it gives me the error:

> Cannot update comment. Only the comment author and project admins can edit a comment.

But I am a project admin, and it still does not work...

Is this a bug, or do I have to set some property to override this behavior?

Using Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client, 16.183.0-preview

Comment: We can see the same issue using Rest API: [Pull Request Thread Comments - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20thread%20comments/update?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#security), it just works when updating the comment which I am the comment author. We suggest that you submit this feedback here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=22&entry=problem, so the product support team will review it and further investigate it.

Comment: I posted a feedback, so that it might fix the issue for others. () To fix this for myself, I edited the comments directly in the Azure DevOps database, which works (and hopefully did not break anything).

Comment: Feedback lin: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-edit-comments-in-Pull-Request/1376731

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stein's feedback. This issue can be reproduced and temporarily we can edit the comments directly in the Azure DevOps database as a workaround. Posting it here so others also could follow this thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-edit-comments-in-Pull-Request/1376731 to get latest feedback from product support team.